# Declarating a variable based on hashes

Tags: ruby

I have two databases: one is old and deprecated; the other one is new, working. Both of them have a table called `brands`.

In the deprecated database, the `brands` table is *something like* the following:

```
id | name
1  | Playstation 1
2  | Playstation 2
3  | Playstation 3
4  | Playstation 4
5  | Xbox
6  | Xbox 360
7  | Xbox One
```

In the new one, this is the `brands` table:

```
id | name
1  | Xbox
2  | Xbox 360
3  | Xbox One
4  | Playstation 1
5  | Playstation 2
6  | Playstation 3
7  | Playstation 4
```

In practice, the scenario is more complex, but the example I gave represents well. So, there's also a `products` table:

```
id | name | brand_id | created_at | updated_at
```

I want to import products from the old database to the new one, but the brands aren't  matching by `id` as you saw. Then, I want to do something like this:

```
brand_id 1 on old_database == brand_id 4 on new_database
```

To be more specific, is kind of a dictionary ***without `ifs`***.

This is what I've done:

```
if query.brand == 1
  brand_id == 4
elsif query.brand == 2
  brand_id = 5
end
```

But this isn't what I really want. Yes, it works, but I want to do something simpler. I think hashes are exactly what I'm looking for. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could declare a hash like this:

```
brand_map = {1 => 4, 2 => 5} # add other entries as needed
```

and then lookup the new id like this:

```
brand_id = brand_map[1]
=> 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it seems that a hash is what you want.  For example,

```
id_map = { 1=>4, 2=>5, ... } # old id => new id
```

then for a record `id, name`, write it to the new database as `id_map(id), name`.